# Change a html link destination on date in the future

Tags: javascript, html

How can i change links destination on date in the future, so is the link is `<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>` and on 31-01-2013 i want it to be `<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">link</a>` ?

fixt :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callFunc() {
    var compareDate = new Date(2014, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var curDate = new Date();
    if (curDate.getTime() > compareDate.getTime()) {
        return "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/";
    } else {
        return "#";
    }
}
document.write('<a href="' + callFunc() + '" target="_blank"><img src="/images/amazon.png" alt="amazon" title="amazon button" width="100%"/></a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your code attempts so far and clarify where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callFunc() {
    var compareDate = new Date(2013, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    alert("compareDate: " + compareDate.toString());
    var curDate = new Date();
    if (curDate.getTime() > compareDate.getTime()) {
        return "http://www.yahoo.com";
    } else {
        return "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
document.write('<a href="' + callFunc() + '">Link</a>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id = "myLink" href = "#">Link</a>

$('#myLink').on('click', function(){
    //compare today's date and set a var url accordingly
     $(location).attr('href', url);
});
```